# R: Accessing elements of 2D matrix with vectors of indices

Tags: r, matrix, vector, 2d

Suppose I have a 3 X 15 matrix "phi", and I want to create a vector of entries from phi corresponding to an i,j combination, where i is a length 900 vector of numbers 1:3, and j is a length 900 vector of numbers 1:15. In other words, I want a length 900 vector of phi values, where the first element is phi[i[1], j[1]], the second element would be phi[i[2], j[2]], etc.

My initial thought was `phi_list <- phi[i, j]`, but that appears to give back every combination of i,j values. So, how would I go about constructing such a vector?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, we can use the index as a `matrix` with the `i` for row index and 'j' for column index

```
phi[cbind(i, j)]
#[1]  6 18 35
```

If we use the `i` and `j`vectors in the 'i', and 'j' it would return a `matrix` by including the rows and columns included in the index instead of picking the elements that matches the location

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
phi <- matrix(1:50, 5, 10)
i <- c(1, 3, 5)
j <- c(2, 4, 7)
```

Comment: Dope, this works! Thanks so much!! Will "accept" this as the answer in, according to Stack Overflow, 10 minutes!